# debug Server less (Node js) locally in Visual code using break points.

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, serverless-framework, serverless

I am new to the serverless framework and is trying to debug Serverless (Node js) locally in Visual code using breakpoints.

I referred to some articles but didn't help me out that much.

https://medium.com/@OneMuppet_/debugging-lambada-functions-locally-in-vscode-with-actual-break-points-deee6235f590
https://hackernoon.com/running-and-debugging-aws-lambda-functions-locally-with-the-serverless-framework-and-vs-code-a254e2011010

Comment: add the problems you encounter specifically.

Comment: If all you are trying to debug is your functionality (and not platform related stuff) why not just run some code that sets up the evn variables + input and then invoke the handler? If you DO wish to debug some of the platform related stuff (e.g event loops, context related) i'm not sure it's possible. This might help but i'm not familiar with that https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/08/introducing-aws-sam-local-a-cli-tool-to-test-aws-lambda-functions-locally/

Answer (score 2):

finally, I was able to fix the issue, I was missing node path

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Debug Local",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "args": [
            "invoke",
            "local",
            "-f",
            "functionname",
            "--path",
            "../test.json", // pass the path of local test event
            "--stage",
            "AWs envrionment name" // eg: dev,stage, prod etc
        ],
        "env": {
            "NODE_PATH": "${cwd}"
        }
    }]
}
```